# Show and hide object on canvas?

Tags: android, object, game-loop

I am developing an Android Games. I have created a canvas on screen. I want to show an object for 2 second on its screen and then it should be disappear.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove your canvas object

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC));
```

else

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep 2 copies of bitmap. On 2nd dont draw the object and draw this 2 bitmaps alternatively, or look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980589/undo-in-a-drawing-app)
will help you